# Sequential I/O performance for old data

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, sequential, hard-drive

I am learning how sequential I/O works in total and with kafka. Per my understanding - all data written to hard disk sequentially (as log), and because of that - hard disk arm is always near by the actual data, it doesn't have to move a lot (because of that we have small/no seek time, same as a write time).

But what if we have a lot of kafka data in HDD (with max allowed retention policy) and new consumer group starting to get this data: as I understand - new consumer group will start reading data from 0 offset and this 0 offset can be in totaly opposite side of HDD (as time passed - HDD arm will be slowly moved around). So, in this case - HDD arm have to go back and forth each time, as old consumers will read the actual data and new consumer group read old data. Won't it lead to opposite effect, so sequential I/O will slow down entire cluster (at least, until new consumer group read all data)?